# Python break outside loop

Tags: python, loops

Whenever I run the code, I get this error. I have also used return command but it still gives error.

```
max_mis = max(np.abs(dx))
if max_mis \<= eps:
  return
eta += 1
```

```
> File "<ipython-input-39-7d7e1824e0be>", line 3
> break
>     ^
> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

I tried using return function, it gave the same error. Changed the spaces, still nothing.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use `return` or `break`? You have neither a function nor a loop.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that actually *has* a `break` statement in it.

Comment: You can only `return` inside a function.  You can only use `break` inside a loop.

Comment: Are you trying to conditionally skip `eta += 1`? Why not something like `if not condition: eta += 1`? Use an `if` statement to increment `eta` when you want, not an if statement to somehow break over it.

Comment: as @FrankYellin has said.   you are using both `break` and `return` incorrectly...